# best way to create example project in a django plugin test suite

Tags: python, django, testing

This may be a simple question, but I can't wrap my head around it.
Given I make a Django plugin app, lets name it `foo`, which adds some database features, that other apps can use (e.g. models that must be inherited), and I want to add tests for that app.
Structure:

```
foo/
  apps.py
  models.py
tests/
  test_foo_basic.py
  test_bar.py
  ...
setup.py
README.md
...
```

The project is no full Django application, as it is an plugin **app** for others. So I need to create a *fake* Django project within the testing directory, with at least one app, which defines some models that inherit from `foo.models.<some_model>` and test it, right?

Is that the only way? It seems a but much for me.

If so, it's ok for me to give me the answer "it is so". And I'll accept ;-)
If not, please tell me I am complicated and show me something easier, a pytest plugin etc.?
For testing, I *need* a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself, after much struggle.

According to [pytest-django docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html#using-django-conf-settings-configure), you can use `pytest_configure()` in `conftest.py` to set up a "pseudo" Django environment for such cases:

```py
# conftest.py

import django
from django.conf import settings


def pytest_configure():
    settings.configure(
        DATABASES={
            "default": {
                "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
                "NAME": ":memory:",
            }
        },
        INSTALLED_APPS=[
            "django.contrib.auth",
            "django.contrib.contenttypes",
            "django.contrib.sessions",
            "django.contrib.messages",
            "django.contrib.staticfiles",
            "django.contrib.sites",
            "your.app"
        ],
    )
    django.setup()
```

This way, you need no `pytest.ini`, no `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env, and the best is: ** You need no complete dummy Django project`

It doesn't help if you need to test project features like module loading, etc. But for simple unit tests, this works perfectly.